# Auth issue with nuget feed in vs2015 on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I am getting one weird issue i.e. auth issue(404 error) while consuming nuget feed(latest version) in my vs 2015 solution using vsts.I am able to access same nuget feed in browser outside of vs2015 but not working in solution.

I am using vs2015 on Windows 10 now but earlier it was working fine on win 8.1.

I have no idea how to proceed with this so i will appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: How did you custom the nugget feed? Do you provided the path for nuget.config file where set the credentials to access nuget gallery under tag "<packageSourceCredentials>"?

Comment: What's the version of VS and nuget? Can you update them to latest version and then try again?